# Vertical Separation of Margins in SVM

Tags: svm

(Cross post from math.stackexchange.com because I just discovered this site)

In a Support Vector Machine, the margins are defined as
$$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x_i}+b\ge1\text{ for }x_i \text{ in class }+1$$
$$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x_i}+b\le-1\text{ for }x_i \text{ in class }-1$$

I understand that minimizing $\Vert w \Vert$ will maximize the distance between the margins given the constraints, however I'm having a hard time with the following:

The margins are set in such a way that their y-intercepts (in 2D space) will always be 2 units apart. It's easy to see how, with this constraint, the distance between the margins will depend only on their angle, but **why would we limit the vertical separation of the margins?** Is there no situation in which the optimal margins would have greater vertical separation?

Edit: Horizontal margin lines come to mind. If the ideal margin lines (again, in 2D space) have a slope of zero, then the distance between them might need to be greater than (or perhaps less than) 2. Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to Andrew Ng's lecture note on SVM [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf) for detailed derivation.
The original optimization is to maximize $\gamma$ with the following constraints:
$$y^{(i)}(w^{T}x^{(i)}+b) \geq \gamma$$
$$||w|| = 1$$ (see page 6 - 7 of the notes).

The second constraint, however, is hard to solve. So, in the derivation, the optimization is transformed from max $\gamma$ to max $\frac{\hat{\gamma}}{||w||}$ (by definition of functional and geometric margin) and the constraint becomes:
$$y^{(i)}(w^{T}x^{(i)}+b) \geq \hat{\gamma}$$

Then, by introducing the scaling constraint for $w$ and $b$ such that $\hat{\gamma} = 1$, the constraint becomes $$y^{(i)}(w^{T}x^{(i)}+b) \geq 1$$

In short, the value 1 in the constraint is simply due to scaling constraint, but the geometric margin $\gamma$ is maximized and can have value greater than 1.

Comment: Those lecture notes are excellent and clear everything up and "In short, the value 1 in the constraint is simply due to scaling constraint" clears things up nicely. Thanks!

Comment: After playing with some examples, I think I've found the source of my confusion: I was forgetting the fact that $\vec{w}$ scales $y$ as well, which ultimately affects the relationship between $b$ and the line's/hyperplane's y-intercept.